# Run-time error "inflating class fragment"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview, android-maps, android-fragmentactivity

I have an activity, what I'm trying to do is to start a new activity that holds a Google Maps Fragment API v2 following this example (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start). I get an runtime error

```
"Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class fragment"
```

This the XML of activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    
   <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/map"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
         class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>   
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the activity's class:

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

```
public class MapsActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_act);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

and this is the logcat:

```
12-18 11:59:37.584: W/dalvikvm(9480): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught    exception (group=0x2b6a3300)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dimacroitori.supermarket/com.dimacroitori.supermarket.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class fragment
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2190)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4939)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class fragment
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:257)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at com.exmaple.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:12)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     ... 11 more
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4656)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     ... 20 more
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
12-18 11:59:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(9480):     ... 23 more
```

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` probably means that you did not add the [library](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) that contains that fragment to your app

Comment: @zapl, sorry for my noob question, but what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have [added the Google Play Services Android library project](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) to your application, where that class is defined. Also make sure that you are running your app on an API Level 11 or higher environment, since you are attempting to use native fragments (rather than the Android Support package's backport).